# PHP explode keywords but dont echo comma on the end

Tags: php, explode

I need a list of keywords to split on 'keyword' but how to dont print the comma on the end, i know to count tags and to check if last tag and to dont display but im interesting in any other clean and good way.

Im using in this way:

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
echo "'" . $keyword . "', ";
}
```

this is printing:

```
'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3',
```

but i like to print without comma in the end, in this way:

```
'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `implode`:
You can try something like:

```
<?php
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
echo "'". implode("', '", $keywords) . "'";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `implode` every elements and print the result:

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
// Add single quotes
$keywords = array_map(function($v) { return "'".$v."'"; }, $keywords);
echo implode(", ", $keywords);
```

Which is the same as (without quotes):

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
echo str_replace(' ', ', ', $keywords);
```

Comment: I definitely agree with you, but he needs single quote too

Answer (score 2):

If I had to do this, I would use a combination of explode, implode and array_map, something like:

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$arrayOfKeywords = explode(' ', $keywords);
$mapped = array_map(function($value) {
    return "'{$value}'";
}, $arrayOfKeywords);

echo implode(', ', $mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
$num =  count($keywords);
$count = 1;
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
if($count == $num){
    echo "'".$keyword."'" ;
} else {
    echo "'".$keyword ."',";
}   
$count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array functions to prepare the string is not the most direct approach.  Better practice would be to simply use `str_replace()` on the delimiting space and manually wrap the string in single quotes.  One-line solution.  No array functions, no iteration.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70a62eb02c697f0d8b0a81044746bc1572f8652e))

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
echo "'",str_replace(' ',"', '",$keywords),"'";
```

Output:

```
'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'
```

This is the "clean" / "good" way.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
 $str = '';
    $keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
    $keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $str .= "'" . $keyword . "',";
    } 
    echo substr($str,0,-1);

rtrim($string, ",") would cut trailing commas.

trim($string, ",") would cut trailing and prefixing commas.

substr($yourstring, 0, -1); //last character.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
$count = 1;
$comma = ',';
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
if($count == 3){
    $comma = '';
}
    echo "'" . $keyword .$comma;
$count++;
}
```